# How to insert the caption in the right side (documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc})?

Tags: positioning, subfloats, overleaf, subcaption

I want to align the sub-caption (c) as in the following figure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim} %comments
\usepackage{apalike}


\usepackage{lipsum,capt-of,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{natbib}
\let\printorcid\relax
\usepackage[wby]{callouts}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=period, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=footnotesize, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}%,skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\sffamily}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx, multirow}
\sisetup{table-format=1.4, tight-spacing=true, separate-uncertainty}

\sisetup{
    output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
    exponent-product={},
    retain-explicit-plus,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=2,
    table-space-text-pre    = (,
    table-space-text-post   = ),
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[table]{captionskip=0.1pt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export, demo]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{clip, trim=1cm 1cm .8cm 0.8cm, width=\linewidth,height=4cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\subfloat[\label{sfig:a}]{\includegraphics{C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf}}
&
\subfloat[\label{sfig:b}]{\includegraphics{C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf}} \\
\subfloat[\label{sfig:c}]{\includegraphics[valign=m]{C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf}}
&
\caption{This caption} \label{fig2: Figs}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your MWE doesn't reproduce showed image. Where you like to have sub-captions labels?

Comment: @Zarko: These sub-captions are in the figures below. But, sub-caption (c) isn't!

Comment: You are mixing 3 different caption packages which is the most likely reason why the output isn't as expected. The assumption is that you want a 2 x 2 layout, with images in the top row and lower-left block, but the caption for the entire figure in the lower-right block. Is this correct?

Comment: @Werner: Yes. I have also changed the code.

Answer (score 3):

Based on guessing what you after. Also after OP's comments and editing of questions.

**Edit:**
Like this?

[image]

or this:

[image]

Instead of `\subfoat` are now used `\subcaption}` defined in `subcaption` package. Subcaptions are places in separated table rows. By this is achieved better control over caption positioning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export, demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{clip, trim=1cm 1cm 1cm 0.8cm, width=\linewidth,height=4cm}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\includegraphics{C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf} \\
\subcaption{}\label{sfig:a}
    &    \subcaption{}\label{sfig:b}    \\
\includegraphics[valign=m]  % for the second image delete "[valign=m]"
                {C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf}
    &   \captionsetup{skip=-2.4ex}
        \caption{\lipsum[1][1]} 
        \label{fig2: neighborhood}      \\
\subcaption{}\label{sfig:c}   
    &                                   \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Similar result can be gottrn if first two images insert in table in `subfloat` environments. In this case the table body is:

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf}}
    &   \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf}} \\
\includegraphics%[valign=m]  % for the second image delete "[valign=m]"
                {C:/Users/foobar/Desktop/Doc1.pdf}
    &   \captionsetup{skip=-2.4ex}
        \caption{\lipsum[1][1]}
        \label{fig2: neighborhood}      \\
\subcaption{}\label{sfig:c}
    &                                   \\
```

Comment: I have used your code in \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}. It is ok. But the caption isn't in its correct position. It is inserted below the sub-figures (not on the right side).

Comment: I have edited my question. I have used your code in Overleaf and got the above image. But the caption isn't on the right side.

Comment: Also, I have an error for `\end{tabularx}`, but the images are achieved.

Comment: @Ellie, see edited answer. Not old MWE nor edited one hasn't any errors. If you not get the same result as are shown in answer, than you change something in MWE or eventually have outdated packages in your LaTeX installation.

Comment: No. Unfortunately, I couldn't solve my problem!